# Can the Google Home hardware communicate directly with an app on the users device?

Tags: android, actions-on-google, google-home

I have been recently looking into the google home hardware and would like to build an assistant app that communicates between the google home hardware and an app on the users device, so far what I have been able to find is that an assistant app can be built that works with a webhook to a backend but not directly to an app on the device which is what I want, is this possible or has this capability not been added as of yet?

[image: An example of assistant interfacing with an installed app]

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "on the device". Do you mean on the Google Home? Do you mean on another device owned by the same account? A home automation-like or IoT device? Are you trying to do this using a local network only? Explaining your use case in more detail in the question will help provide a better answer.

Comment: Hi sorry, so by device I meant the users android device, when the user sets up the Google home they use their android device to set it up so I was hoping that an app installed on the Android device could communicate directly with the Google home

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a feature does not exist, nor is it really likely to exist in the future in the way you describe. Google Home is just one device that supports the Google Assistant, and many of these others have other setup and linking abilities and requirements.

You don't indicate what your use case is, but it sounds like you might want to investigate [Account Linking](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/account-linking) which will let your Action key data (such as commands) against your user's account id. You can then use something like Firebase Database or Firebase Cloud Messaging to update data or trigger an event in your app.

Comment: (1) Thanks for this reply Its helped me clear up a couple things, one final question however, currently if you're using the google assistant on an android device and say "send a voice message on whatsapp" you're taken to a full screen ui that seems to have been styled by the developer that looks like their app, I am not sure if this is part of the conversational ui or an actual activity in their app, however if the app is not already installed you will receive a message that says "whatsapp is either not installed or needs to be updated"

Comment: (2) There seems to be a very tight correlation between the installed android app and the google assistant app here, what mechanism are they achieving this through? I'll add a screenshot to my original question above if it helps